# Why cant I see the 'UIViewController subclass' under Cocoa touch for ios/macos?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I'm a newbie, and plainly started with a sample code from the book 'Beginning-iOS-5-Games-Development'. 
Everything seems quite straight-forward, but i cant see the UIViewController subclass under the Cocoa touch for both ios/macos...
Would this have anything to do with the fact that the example is trying to work with Universal device type. 
My Xcode version is 4.3.2, and im trying out ios5...

thanks for your help..

user

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to select `Objective-C class`, then click `Next`.  On the next screen, you can specify that the class you are making is a subclass of `UIViewController`.